# How to add a Toast notification with delay after I log in

Tags: reactjs

This is my code, so I need to add a toast.succes notification after I log in to the website the problem is that after I add my data the website take me to the home page and the notification do not appear.

I need maybe a delay function to put it on the home page.

There's a pic of my loginForm component.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNQQn.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To start, please add the code to the post and not as an image.

Comment: Are you using react-router?